# Alfresco Share Workflow show variable on start

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am creating a custom workflow in share and everything works perfectly until when I wanted to show logged user details like first name, last name, email, department, telephone etc on the share form when I click on start workflow. Is it possible to show these variables before the process instance has been started? If yes, how do i do this? If no, what is the work around of this ?

Kindly assist

Comment: Just so I understand your question, do you want these details to be shown before the workflow is started, or immediately after?

Comment: @Alan George I want the details to be shown before the workflow is started.

Answer (score 0):

To show your form in the custom workflow you need to add related configuration in the alfresco share.
For Instance

My workflow name is  "myCustomWorkflow" then you can define config in your **share-config-custom.xml** which will configure the workflow form.

```
<config evaluator="string-compare" condition="activiti$myCustomWorkflow">
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below answer.

[Alfresco: Defining new Control-Params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30901891/alfresco-defining-new-control-params/30906853#30906853).

In ftl file ,you can use javascript object and print current logged in user in first form , even though your workflow is not started.There are more than one way to achieve this.This is one of them.